# How do I split the lists in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a list
`['x1_0','x2_1','x3_0']` How can I split the above list into two lists such that the first list contains
`['x1','x2','x3']` and the second list `[0,1,0]`?
i.e.

```
         ('x1_0')
         /    \
        /      \
       /        \
     1st list   2nd list
      'x1'          0
```

Feel free to use as many tools as possible. This could obviously done in a single for loop ,which I am aware of. Is there a better way to do this ?.
Something which uses list comprehension ?
Als

Comment: What are `x1_0`? Variable names?

Comment: I guess, x1 and 0 are two lists as per him. @myaut

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and a list comprehension :

```
>>> zip(*[i.split('_') for i in l])
[('x1', 'x2', 'x3'), ('0', '1', '0')]
```

And if you want to convert the second tuple's elements to int  you can use the following nested list comprehension :

```
>>> [[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in tup] for tup in zip(*[i.split('_') for i in l])]
[['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], [0, 1, 0]]
```

The preceding way is the proper way to do this task but as you say in comment as a smaller solution you can use `map` :

```
>>> l=[l[0],map(int,l[1])]
>>> l
[('x1', 'x2', 'x3'), [0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: @vks its for unpacking! checkout the link!

Comment: @vks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters

Comment: how do I convert elements in the second list into integers.

Comment: @PalashAhuja you can use `int` function,check the edit!

Answer (score 1):

```
k=["x1_0","x2_1","x3_0"]
k1=[x.split("_")[0] for x in k]
k2=[int(x.split("_")[1]) for x in k]
```

You can do this simply this way.